# Avoiding "setting with copy habits" warning - developing bad habits?

Tags: python, pandas

Important info: I am generally using pandas and matplotlib as the relevant modules here, though I move data in and out of numpy-explicit code to do certain operations (SVD specifically).

Last week a bunch of code that had been running without warning/error suddenly started producing `setting with copy` warnings. I must have had an update occur that undid some settings or other. In learning about and correcting these warnings, I started a default practice of always specifying a column using .loc. For example, I need a list of unique variables in a sample ID column (there are many duplicates for reasons).

```
list1=(PCspectra_to_plot.loc[:,sampleid].unique())
```

I now *always* use that `.loc[:,columnname]` convention to specify using all rows and a specific column, and the `setting with copy warning`is a thing of the past.

My question is: where could this habit lead me into trouble? Is this just good convention, or is there a place where `.loc` could produce other errors (or .iloc, when I want to use index values).

Comment: What library / module are you using

Comment: Of course, sorry, I'm generally running between pandas, numpy, and matplotlib (plus some other matplotlib modules). Comment updated.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I'd say your current approach (using .loc rather than .iloc) should help prevent some further errors since your code wouldn't be affected by a change in the order of columns. But it's hard to generalise from such little information. For me, it was usually triggered when I used chained assignments. If you restructured your code so that the warning is gone, it seems that you improved the structure.

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ <- This article might give you a few pointers on how to avoid the warning at all or dealing with it.